# why IO::Socket always gets TIMEOUT?

Tags: perl

whenever I try to connect with perl Socket it gets timeout... like this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use v5.26;
use IO::Socket;


my $sock = IO::Socket::INET->new(PeerAddr=> 'www.google.com',
                             PeerPort => 'http(80)',
                             Proto    => 'tcp') or die $!;

my $line = <$sock>;
say $line;
```

can anyone tell me why...

Comment: If you want to talk to a HTTP server, you should use a HTTP client module...

Comment: can you give me an example please...

Comment: Anyways, what's timing out? The read?  (A HTTP server isn't going to send any data until you send a request) And how? Where is there a timeout in the code you posted?

Comment: socket (my $sock, AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, $protocol) or die "can't make socket: $!"; connect ($sock, $destination) or die "can't connect: $!"; it can not connect and timed out

Comment: That line doesn't appear in the code you posted. You should show what you're actually using.

Comment: You connect alright but there's nothing to read (it waits on the next line).  Send something, like `say $sock "hi";`, and you'll get something back (400 in this case).

Comment: THNX, you are right... what should I send to get proper response?

Comment: @MaaniDelaavari: if you want to get a proper response you need to send a proper HTTP request. In the most simple case this is `GET / HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: www.google.com\r\n\r\n`. But note that HTTP is way more complex than this small example and there is usually also TLS involved today for HTTPS. I recommend to study the actual standard if you really want to write your own HTTP client instead of using existing libraries.

Comment: Talking HTTP directly with the server is (needlessly) low-level. Why do you want to do that?  If it's for play and learning then I'd recommend that you read and learn about it first, as it is not so simple (see the comment by @SteffenUllrich).  Otherwise, there are excellent tools and frameworks in Perl, such as `LWP::UserAgent`, `Mojo::UserAgent`, ...

Answer (score 3):

In a conversation with a web server, the user-agent speaks first. You haven't sent a request. The server waits for you to send the request then gives up. If you want to make web requests, something like [Mojo::UserAgent](https://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojo/UserAgent) will do most of the work for you.

Also realize that some hosts may be wise to you. It's better to test this sort of stuff locally instead.